# SqlException in .updateall after convert OLEDB to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding, datagridview, sqlexception

I'm writing an app in C# with a MS Access backed (`.accdb`). I made the call (on advisement) that SQL Server was a much better idea for my system, thus I spent the last 8 hrs re-coding to SQL Server.

As a background;

- Changed all OLEDB connection, command etc etc to Sql
- Fixed all parameters and variables from `?` to `@value`
- Fixed all SQL string errors

Now all my forms are working with the exception of the ones using BINDING done by Visual Studio 'wizard' (if that's what it's called).

I have 5 forms which are filled using

```
this.tbljobTableAdapter.Fill(this.websterdbDataSet.tbljob);
```

They are all using a `DataGridView` depending upon that info.

On "Save and Close", this code runs:

```
this.Validate();
this.tbluserBindingSource.EndEdit();

this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.websterdbDataSet);

_owner.PerformRefresh();
this.Close();
this.Dispose();
```

This works 100% still with my `.ACCDB` version (I'm checking from a backup) but not now that it is SQL Server.

If I press Save and Close and haven't changed ANYTHING, it closes, but if I change any field at all it fails with this (from my log):

> Data Time:21/08/2017 12:12:20 AM
>   Exception Name:Incorrect syntax near '`'.
>   Event Name:System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs
>   Control Name:BtnSave
>   Error Line No.:86
>   Form Name:frmjoblist

Any ideas how I can further debug this?

I thought it was something I did when adding Try and Catch to all my sections, but in the end this is happening to the specific 5 forms that I used the wizard instead of manually creating, binding and writing SQL update strings for.

Thanks for any advice/direction.

GAngel

Comment: The error is in the query statement.  The Adapter has a command which contains the "Command Text".  The error is in the string for the command text which you did not post.

Comment: Great thanks jdweng,  Found it!
now to fix it :P  When i change from OLEDB to SQL to make it.. faster i replaced all "?" with "@" then i could just write variables in.  Well all my table adapters arent fixed yet so i think i have some work ahead of me!!

Is there a way to recreate the adapters? Or just recreate the datagridviews..

Comment: So pretty much i need it to re-build the designer section for the dataset, as it has built them orignally in OLEDB...

Comment: @jdweng Any ideas on how i can rebuild my table adapters, or should i just delete the tables in dataset and rebuild using new string hopefully!

Comment: An Adapter has a SQL Command.  The command has four queries : Select, Delete, Insert, and Update.  Each query has a command text.  So you should be able to modify the properties of adapter to change the string.

Answer (score 0):

So the deisgner was still all in OLEDB, therefore I ended up deleting the dataset and recreating using the correct connection which rebuilt the designer in SQL